# Debug target is an old version of NUnit that isn't present on computer

Tags: visual-studio-2012, nunit

When trying to debug a project which I have successfully debugged many times before and which compiles without incident, I'm now getting this error:

> Visual Studio cannot start debugging because the debug target 'C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit 2.6.2\bin\nunit.exe' is missing. Please build the project and retry, or set the OutputPath and AssemblyName properties appropriately to point at the correct location for the target assembly.

Looking at Program Files (x86), I can see that the reason VS can't find the file is that it doesn't exist. The version of NUnit it should be looking for is 2.6.4, not 2.6.2.

What I can't find, however, is any way to tell VS where to look. The `OutputPath` and `AssemblyName` properties referenced in the error message  both seem unrelated to the issue, and there isn't any setting I can find that references NUnit at all, much less a particular version of it.

---

In following advice from some of the many other questions about this error, I have tried the following without success:

- Cleaning and rebuilding the solution
- Cleaning and rebuilding the individual projects within the solution
- Looking at the project and solution files in a text editor (They all show NUnit 2.6.4)
- Making sure the projects are all checked in the Configuration Manager
- [Checking the projects' debug properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25221088/2308973)

Comment: I think if you want to get an answer to this you are going to need to post the .csproj file for the project you are trying to debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated above, neither the .sln files nor any of the .csproj files contained any reference to NUnit 2.6.2, but I finally found a reference to it in a .csproj.user file for one of the projects:

```
<StartProgram>C:\Program Files %28x86%29\NUnit 2.6.2\bin\nunit.exe</StartProgram>
```

Changing the version number there fixed the issue.