# The name "ImageViewModel" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:AdminControlCenter.ViewModel"

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

As the titel say i have the problem that Xaml don´t now my clr namespace, I read the other posts and tried their solution without any success, I rebuild, Start as Admin tried the build conviguration etc.

My Project looks so:

[image]

My XAML:

```
<Controls:MetroWindow  x:Class="AdminControlCenter.View.MainView"
    xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:resx="clr-namespace:AdminControlCenter.Properties;assembly=AdminControlCenter"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AdminControlCenter;assembly=AdminControlCenter"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:AdminControlCenter.ViewModel;assembly=AdminControlCenter"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="400" Width="600">


<Grid  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="White">
    <Grid.DataContext>
        <vm:ImageViewModel x:Name="imageViewModel"/>
    </Grid.DataContext>
```

And the Error:

[image]

And the ImageViedModel:

```
namespace AdminControlCenter.ViewModel
{
public class ImageViewModel : ViewModel
{
    public ImageViewModel()
    {

    }
.....
```

The classes are public and show up at the autoformat, when I type for example
"vm:"  It also go to the Definition of the Class by using F12.

When I use some MVVM tutorial tests, they are working. But when I try in my Project all ViewModels are not found.

Why doesen´t found the XAMl my ViewModels ?

Edit:
I tried every variation of the assemblies with and without, I also try to delete the suo and try every build configuration, and I restart VS as Admin etc. I also make a new Project with another name and rewrite all classes (Not Copied them) also without any success

Comment: Did you build your project? You **have to** build your project, before XAML will Recognize types

Comment: Yes Build, Rebuild, Clean, restart as admin I stuck in this error since Wednesday.....

Comment: Check the namespace declaration in ImageViewModel.cs. Is it actually `AdminControlCenter.ViewModel`?

Comment: Yes I Edit the question and copied it

Comment: can you try to rename the base ViewModel "Viewmodel" To "ViewModelBase".I am not sure but there is chance that xaml may get confused from Viewmodel folder and class.

Comment: I renamed it and tried again with and without assembly but it didn´t work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get this error too sometimes, but I can build/deploy anyway.. I think it's a Visual Studio bug.. Are you able to deploy your solution?
Maybe you can try to copy Model and ViewModel's content somewhere else , delete from the project these two files and recreate the files again.. Or.. Do you know how to use the ViewModelLocator class? Since I started use it I never seen that issue again

See here for details about ViewModelLocator: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5462040/what-is-a-viewmodellocator-and-what-are-its-pros-cons-compared-to-datatemplates)

Comment: The Programm compiles sometimes the othertimes I get this error for some reasons idk... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563691/c-sharp-debug-cannot-start-debugging-because-the-debug-target-is-missing i tried to delete the classes and move them but with no success and the error was gone for at least 30minutes but then it comes this error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3087390/the-source-file-is-different-from-when-the-module-was-built and after a restart I get status quoe again

Comment: Try with ViewModelLocator, work like a charm for me!