# Visual Studio cannot start debugging because the debug target is missing. error still continues

Tags: c#, visual-studio

> Visual Studio cannot start debugging because the debug target is missing

I looked up a lot of solutions for this error, but none of them worked for me. I tried everything, but still I have no solution.

When I click run, this infamous error message shows up.

I have set my output path to the correct folder, and everything. nothing works
please help!

Comment: Are you sure that your build is succeeding?

Comment: On the Project settings page, (is it the 'Debug' tab?... I'm not at my computer) there is an option to say what you want to start when you start debugging. Also re-set which project is your start-up project.

Comment: It would help if you showed the full text of the error message (pressing CTRL+C while the error messagebox is displayed will copy the text to the clipboard).  It might also help if you told us what settings you have on the Build and Debug pages of your project properties.

Comment: P.S. *"I looked up a lot of solutions for this error, but none of them worked for me"*... If you read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)... you should say specifically what your research found and tried, so we don't waste time suggesting the same thing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Debug - cannot start debugging because the debug target is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563691/c-sharp-debug-cannot-start-debugging-because-the-debug-target-is-missing)

Comment: VS normally displays a warning first.  That warning has a "don't show this again" checkbox, annoyed programmers have a knack for ticking that box.  Hoping that makes things get better, it doesn't.  Fix the settings, use Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Build and Run.  Change "On run, when projects are out of date" to [Always build].  And "On run, when build or deployment error occurs" to [Do not launch].  Now you won't get this error anymore and you are more likely to discover the Error List window (shows compile errors) and the Output window (shows the build result)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

**right click solution -> Property -> Configuration Properties ->Configuration -> Enable project in Build**

from [visual studio development center](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/3696892-visual-studio-cannot-start-debugging-because-the-d)

Comment: You say to "Right click solution". I dont see a solution tab anywhere. What do you mean by that?

Comment: your solution in visual studio

Answer (score 0):

Hi this happened to me after I renamed Form1. I tried Bulding/Rebulding/Cleaning the Project, changing the path etc. but nothing worked. The Debug folder of the project was empty and then I saw that there is error in the Program.cs, the old name of the form was not updated to the new name. So in the Program.cs change the Old name with the new Form Name. This Solved my problem and now the application is working.This could be the problem if you are using Win Forms. 
[image: Image1]

[image: Image2]

[image: Image3]