# C# Windows form app getting expected errors

Tags: c#

When i try to start this program it says cannot start debugging because the debug target is missing, someone told me that i need to fix all the errors but idk how to fix them can some1 help me. (im a beginner this is for a school project and it would really help me if someone can help because i don't know what to do)

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Palindroomapp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int i, startchar, lastchar;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
         string low = textBox2.Text.ToLower()

         

         char[] character = new char[60];
         character = low.ToCharArray();
         startchar = 0;
         lastchar = character.Lenght - 1;
         while (startchar < lastchar)

            {
                if (character[startchar] == character[lastchar])
                {
                    startchar++;
                    lastchar--;



                }
                else
                {
                    label2.Visible = true;
                    label2.Text = "Dit is geen palindroom";
                    button2.Text = "Probeer het opnieuw";
                    textBox2.Focus()

                    i = 2;

                    break;


                }


            }
          if (i < 2)
        {
        
        
        label2.Visible = true;
        label2.Text = "Dit is een palindroom";
        button2.Text = "Probeer een ander woord";
        textBox2.Focus();
        }
         else
         {

           i = 0;


         }



            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Check you've selected startup project is executable. Otherwise, check there is error when build.

Comment: if you mixed something up in the project and project is small. The easy way will be create new project and past code.

Comment: You can get the answer in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563691/c-sharp-debug-cannot-start-debugging-because-the-debug-target-is-missing) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563691/c-sharp-debug-cannot-start-debugging-because-the-debug-target-is-missing Its answered